# VB.NET Application Freezed and not running

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, stream, webclient

I have an application that uses a loop to call a new thread with some parameters, the application is great but when it comes to 100,000 records or so the application is not running (in the CPU and memory taskmgr not change, therefore assume that the program is not working)

The action is:
It runs a function that first collects a number (X) and then create a loop from 0 to X, within this loop we create a new Thread and options as indicated IsBackground (True), Priority (Normal), and initialize the thread.
In the same function Thread.Join have a Do While (true) and if you can cross it refreshed interface, abort thread, memory clean and DoEvents!

Within the thread use a WebClient to OpenRead and keep all this in a Stream.
With WebClient.IsBusy = False Do While we ensure that the information is downloaded and proceed to make a MatchCollection with Regex.Match.
Using a For Each the match and print results, and ended Exit Do.

Then returns to the function that tells a while back ...

At first I thought it was because of the number of results that were printed in the listbox but I got it and still fails, not when it reaches the 100,000 records if not the 100,800 or so.

I need help, I don't know very well programming in vb.net and not understand why.

EDIT:
I tried remove the For Each of thread, check whether it was.
It has emerged completely, but I do not understand why it happens not even give me an error when "For Each" in the thread ¿solutions?

---

EDIT:
I found the bug, but i don't understand i explain:

A) --> Initialize function with For 0 to 4500, i call a thread with parameters and receive 50 results, ( 225000 registers <- 4500 * 50 ) when the principal For arrive to ~ 4000, in MatchCollection in Thread ¿fails? i don't receive the info of Regex.Matches and then freezed.

B) --> Initialize function with For 4000 to 4500, i call a thread with parameters and receive 50 results, ( 225000 registers <- 4500 * 50 ), nothing more begin the first thread (  remember now begin with 4000 to 4500 and i have receive a 25000 registers ) the program is freezed and i check with break points and fails the variable containing the results of Regex.Matches and attempting looping the that array the program are freezed!

¿Why? ¿Solutions?

Thanks!!

---

Function 1 (Inicialize Thread)

Function 1 ->

```
For Me.d = 0 To Pages(0) ' <-- 4500
        Dim param(1) As Object
        param(0) = "name"
        param(1) = "url/" & d
        Dim thread As New Thread(AddressOf Thread_)
        thread.IsBackground = True
        thread.Name = "name"
        thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal 'ThreadPriority.Lowest
        thread.Start(param)
        Do While thread.Join(True)
            thread = Nothing
            ClearMemory()
            Application.DoEvents()
            Exit Do
        Loop
    Next d
```

The Thread function:

```
Public Sub Thread_(ByVal param As Object)
    Try
        If param(0) = "name" Then
            Using Client As New WebClient
                Client.Headers("User-Agent") = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1290.1 Safari/537.13"
                Dim html As Stream = Client.OpenRead(param(1))
                Using reader As New StreamReader(html)
                    Do While wc.IsBusy = False
                        Dim ReadStr = reader.ReadToEnd
                        links = Regex.Matches(ReadStr, "coderegex", RegexOptions.Compiled + RegexOptions.RightToLeft + RegexOptions.Multiline + RegexOptions.Singleline)
                        For Each match In links
                            Registres(0) = Registres(0) + 1
                            Debug.Print("Registro: " & Registres(0) & " pág:" & PagesComplete(0))
                        Next
                        PagesComplete(0) = PagesComplete(0) + 1
                        links = Nothing
                        Client.Dispose()
                        Exit Do
                    Loop
                End Using
            End Using
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Print("Error " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: you mean the X = 100,000? 1st, you cannot use so many threads. 2nd, sounds like the threads are locked.

Comment: But, when the thread finalize, i abort the thread, so the principal loop of 0 to X inicialize again the thread with parameters, i don't know why the application stop at ~ 100.000 registers but if delete the line of "For Each" for found the Regex.Match counting the registers, he arrived to X perfect!

Comment: Hmmmm, i found the the bug, but i don't understand: When i have a ~ 100,000 registers, 4000 in the for principal to call the thread -- when arrive to thread and make a MatchCollection with Regex.Matches, the variable don't  receives the info and take the error: "Error evaluating property"

Comment: Your English is hard to decode, let the code do the talking instead.  Post a snippet.  Other than that, using DoEvents and Thread.Abort() are very good ways to create deadlock.

Comment: Sorry for my English, i edited and put the code. The bug is in the thread function when declare links ( Public links As MatchCollection ) = Regex...

Comment: I don't think it is the cause of your problem, but the `RegexOptions` should combined using `Or` instead of `+`, and if you want the regex to be compiled only once, (although I think there is caching to avoid this sort of issue) you should create it once separately and then use that object to generate `Matches`.

Answer (score 0):

This part looks suspicous:

```
Do While thread.Join(True)
    thread = Nothing
    ClearMemory()
    Application.DoEvents()
    Exit Do
Loop
```

shouldn't that look like this:

> ```
> thread.Join()
> thread = Nothing
> ClearMemory()
> ```

If you're using framework >=4 then you might consider using Parallel.For ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). Instead of creating your own threads you let the framework handle it for you.